# Best model to analyse influence of variable

Tags: regression, correlation

I have a dataset with results from sport exercises. It was a study to determine the influence of caffeine on the performance of athlets. The sportsmen were splitted in 2 groups. 1 placebo group and 1 group who consumed caffein. It looks like this:

```
name   exercise1    exercise2    exercise3    caffeine (1=consumed, 0=consumed not)

Tom    10.3         44           5.8          1       
Bob    9            62           5.2          0
Tim    12           33           6.2          1
...
```

Which method do you recommend to analyze if caffein has an influence on the performance?
Association analysis? Correlation analysis? Regression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us assume you have enough observations in each group such that it is possible to use the Central Limit Theorem and thus we can deal with Normally distributed observations.

For your caffeine groupe (C) and your non-caffeine group (NC), you will need the several information for both groups:

- $n_j$, the number of data points for each group
- $\bar{x}_j$, the average of your "response variable"
- $s_j$, the standard deviation of your "response variable."

You then go on to test:
$H_0:\mu_C=\mu_{NC}$ or, equivalently, $H_0:\mu_C-\mu_{NC}=0$

against the alternative:

$H_A:\mu_C\neq\mu_{NC}$ (or $<$ or $>$.) In your case, it looks like a one-sided test, so I would go for the latter.

The test statistic is: $t=\frac{(\bar{x}_C-\bar{x}_{NC})-0}{\sqrt{\frac{s^2_C}{n_C}+\frac{s^2_{NC}}{n_{NC}}}}$

where $t$ follows a $t$-distribution of degrees of freedom $r$ such that: $r=\frac{(\frac{s^2_C}{n_C}+\frac{s^2_{NC}}{n_{NC}})^2}{\frac{(s^2_C/n_C)^2}{n_C-1}+\frac{(s^2_{NC}/n_{NC})^2}{n_{NC}-1}}$. 
Note that we then take the integer value of $r$.

We can then test using a standard $t$-test with significance level $\alpha$ and degrees of freedom $r$.

Comment: On a related note, running a regression with a single dummy variable as an explanatory variable is the same as a test of equality of means.